# Uploading Images to Facebook

Tags: firefox, facebook

I use Facebook via Firefox.

I have a directory with 30 images and I want to upload some (maybe 4 of them) to facebook.

I tried two ways:

1: Start inside facebook via firefox: click on Foto/Images. Now a file selection dialog opens. But the preview is way to small. I can't decide inside this dialog which files I want to upload.

2: I start inside nautilus. There I can enlarge the preview with ctrl-+. I select some images and press ctrl-c to copy them. I go to firefox and press ctrl-v into the textarea of facebook. Now the filenames get copied into the textarea in ascii. That's not what I want.

... How to easily select some images and upload them to facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I logged into Facebook with Firefox and see what you are talking about. The images are super tiny in the image upload dialog. On mine though, when you select an image in that dialog, then you get a larger preview on the right side. I don't know why your preview pane on the right is missing.

As far as your second attempt, instead of copy/pasting, try dragging the desired pictures from Nautilus on top of the Facebook post dialog. That works for me.

I made a video of me uploading a picture to Facebook. I hope it posts ok.

https://www.screencast.com/t/WlFEDMAhqoM